# How do I boot Debian from an EFI file

Tags: debian, boot

The hard drive contains 2 operating systems Windows and Debian. When I press F2 on startup laptop display a menu with 2 choices, boot from master hard drive or from an EFI file. Master hard drive boot starts only windows.

The EFI boot option contains only one directory that I suspect is some free dos that the laptop has originally...

How do i put and EFI file for debian in that menu? Thanks

**Note:** the only functional operating system that I have right now is windows, I can't format and reinstall, I have to fix the Debian boot from Windows.

Comment: What is partitioning on drive? If MBR(msdos) then Windows is in BIOS boot mode (not recommended unless system prior to 2012). To boot in UEFI, you would have to convert from MBR to gpt which totally erases the drive. You must have all systems in same boot mode or all BIOS or all UEFI. Post this from Ubuntu terminal: `sudo parted -l` & `lsblk -f`

Comment: If you attempt an UEFI install, it moves boot, esp flags to the ESP - efi system partition. But Windows requires the boot flag on the Windows boot partition if in BIOS mode. You may be able to move boot flag back to Windows boot partition (one with bootmgr & BCD) to boot in old BIOS mode. But better to totally start over. Windows requires gpt partitioning for UEFI boot which will totally erase drive. Create new Windows installer in one flash drive & new Debian installer in another & totally reinstall. Back up any data  you want first.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you had had Debian installed and then you installed Windows and assumed that you will be able to dual boot - if I'm correct, split your problem into two parts:

1. **Your Windows was installed and using "Legacy boot mode"** - you cannot use EFI in this case.
2. **Debian bootloader was replaced/overwritten with Windows Bootloader** - Windows Bootloader natively cannot boot Debian.

**Solution:**

Use Debian installer to find and fix your Debian Linux installation on your disk - just boot from the USB flash you used for installation and follow the instructions (the new versions of Debian should find your installation automatically and ask you to decide). The installer put GRUB2 upon the Windows Bootloader and allow you to dual-boot both systems.

Comment: Note: the F2 menu might offer two ways to boot the Debian installer - one of these will be UEFI and the other is legacy-style. Find out which boot method is used by Windows, and use the same method to boot the Debian installer, so it will install the appropriate variant of GRUB2. To find the boot method used by Windows, open Device Manager -> Firmware -> System Firmware. If on General tab it says "Location: on Microsoft UEFI-Compliant System", Windows is using UEFI boot method.

Comment: @TelcoM: Thanks for your comment - exactly part “how to check the actual boot mode”... In the question is written that system boots only from “master drive but not from EFI” so the Legacy mode is probably used. Should I add your note into the Q itself (and how - with the respect that you mentioned it)? (Sorry, this is my first answer.)

Comment: Feel free to add it any way you like. I agree with your estimate that Legacy mode is probably used, but it's best to be 100% sure. The system is clearly UEFI-capable, and it is important to avoid the common mistake of installing one OS (or its bootloader) to boot in Legacy mode and another in UEFI mode.

Comment: Indeed, BIOS (that thing) in the boot option has a ''legacy support'' option and it was enabled since ever. I disabled it and then ''save and exit'' and it displays a terminal whch say that I have no opereting system and I have to instal one. Therefore I can't disable legacy mode or it doesn't boot not even in free dos. please explain

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live debian USB then reinstall grub as described in [Reinstalling grub-efi on your hard drive](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall#Reinstalling_grub-efi_on_your_hard_drive)

```
mkdir /mnt/boot/efi
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi # /dev/sda1=EFI partition
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt  # root partition
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
apt install os-prober
apt install --reinstall grub-efi
```

In case of failure ([problem1](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall#Problem1:_Weak_EFI_implementation_only_recognizes_the_fallback_bootloader)), run:

```
cp debian/grubx64.efi boot/bootx64.efi
```

Then:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

or:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sda
```

or:

```
 grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=debian --recheck --debug /dev/sda
```

Exit the chroot and unmout partitions:

```
exit
for i in /sys /proc /dev; do umount /mnt$i; done
umount /mnt/boot/efi
umount /mnt
```

Comment: The file that I used to instal Debian was: debian-10.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso downloaded from the debian official site.
It's not on the USB media anymore if it is not good for ''live debian USB'' please give me a link with the proper file. Thank you